# What function does Bonfire use to hash passwords?

Tags: php, codeigniter, bonfire

I don't know if this is CI or Bonfire specific question and I realize it isn't a specific programming question but it sure hinders my ability to code in that environment.

Under `bonfire/modules/users/controllers/users/` is a controller that uses a nifty function called `login()`. I use that function and frameworks function `register()` to take care of all my login/registration needs but now when I have to make a Facebook login by scratch I need to compare 2 passwords.

Problem is I can't compare passwords because they are hashed by some funky weird hash with salt added and I can't figure out what do they use and answer is nowhere to be found!

My database stores hashes like `$2a$08$QuJPuhhg.HYh8o7ybGJ1quFe1rvcIo/dRIPJ.iaSbHm5P2qAbPTNy` I know I shouldn't compare passwords but in this case I need them compared because I am making Facebook login and I need to see if user with that id already exists in a database. And id in this case is stored as a password of the user.

So what function does the framework use to hash passwords?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CI Bonfire uses **[phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)** *(pronounced "pH pass")* framework in order to hash passwords.

When you **[create](https://github.com/ci-bonfire/Bonfire/blob/develop/bonfire/modules/users/models/user_model.php#L286)** or **[update](https://github.com/ci-bonfire/Bonfire/blob/develop/bonfire/modules/users/models/user_model.php#L346)** a user, bonfire uses [`Auth::hash_password()`](https://github.com/ci-bonfire/Bonfire/blob/2920c6afd529ffcd7e5fed2334074d72af88d41f/bonfire/modules/users/libraries/auth.php#L661) method (which loads the phpass framework under the hood!) to create the hashed password.

**Example**

```php
$password = $this->auth->hash_password('password');
$hash = $password['hash'];
$iterations_used = $password['iterations'];
```

Hence you could use that method manually to hash any string using the same algorithm.

Also there's a [`check_password()`](https://github.com/ci-bonfire/Bonfire/blob/2920c6afd529ffcd7e5fed2334074d72af88d41f/bonfire/modules/users/libraries/auth.php#L702-L718) method in **Auth** library which compares two parameter: The input string (`password`) as the first parameter and the hashed password (`hash`) as the second one. It could be helpful for comparing purposes.

**Example**

```php
if ($this->auth->check_password('password to check', 'HashedPassword'))
{
    // The passwords match
    ...
}
```

It returns `bool(true)` if the password and hash match, else `false`.

These methods are also documented in the [Bonfire user guide](http://cibonfire.com/docs/developer/roles_and_permissions#passwords).